# Function failed when called from other project due to assembly file c#

Tags: c#, signalr

I have a c# solution with 2 projects. one of them is a server (The server was build using signalR) which activates a Hub.
The second is a windows form project which suppose to output a basic window, in the constructor of this window I call the following function (from the first project)
[image]
this function suppose to activate the server.

However when I run this line `dis = WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:10476");` I get the following exception 
`"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"`

So do you know what is the problem? should I install signalR also for the second project?(it sounds inefficient)

Comment: See following.  Did you setup self host? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/older-versions/self-host-a-web-api

Comment: Please include code as text, not as an image...

Comment: When you post code to Stack Overflow, it's better to copy the code as text into you question (formatted as Code).  A picture of your code can't be copy/pasted anywhere useful